# How to delete Ubuntu without damaing another Linux distro?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub2

I have 3 partitions on my computer they're dual-boot, Red Hat, Ubuntu & Windows 8. I want to get rid of Ubuntu and keep Red Hat & Windows 8. What would be the safest route to achieve my goal.

[image]

[image: Df -h]

Comment: This can be an easy task, but it really depends on your setup. Which boot loader are you using? Which partition is it installed on? Has each OS been installed on a separate partition?

Comment: I have separate partitions for each OS, but how do I know which partition is which? I don't want to delete the wrong one. So what i got from your reply is that I need to find the partition of my OS and just delete it? @Bananguin

Comment: It can be this easy, but it needn't be. That's why I asked many questions (the list is not exhaustive) to motivate you to tell us more about your set up. We cannot know which OS you put on which partition. You will have to find out. The command `mount` will be very helpful for this task. You have to boot into one of your Linuxes, mount all three partitions (one should be mounted as `/` already) and find out which partition shelters which OS. Then you need to find out which boot loader you are using, where it is installed and how it is configured, because we cannot tell.

Comment: @Bananguin does gparted help? If i were to to delete the windows partition would that get rid of it? Also where would all the left over GB would go to? does it automatically go to my primary partition or do I have to allocate it into my ubuntu? or red hat?

Comment: From the UI It looks like you are on your Ubuntu when obtaining this screenshot of Gparted -- if this isn't true then let me know because you have some clues in the screenshot already, just a little more is needed. What else is needed is can you run `df -h` and update your question to include this info, thanks

Comment: Yes I am running it from ubuntu

Comment: @user454038 I added a screenshot of the command output

Comment: From the df [under Ubuntu], it looks like the Ubuntu rootfs is /dev/sda10.  From gparted, sda10 is ext4.  The only other ext4 partition is sda8.  That's probably redhat.  If you boot redhat, do df, you'll probably see that it thinks its rootfs is /dev/sda8--that's confirmation.  Then, you can use gparted to delete the sda8 partition

Comment: Thanks! So by having those two screenshots, it is reasonable that, in Gparted, ext4 #1 having 112.75G , that is your Ubuntu, so ext4 #2 is Red Hat. Do you remember which OS was installed last?

Comment: If you follow @CraigEstey's `delete the sda8` advice then you may lose your Red Hat. But unless you changed your mind, your question says you want to lose the Ubuntu, not the Red Hat, so just beware ...

Comment: I installed Red Hat last, but it wasn't working at first so I installed it several time, I think it was 2 times to be specific. @user454038 So do  I just need to delete `ext4` if I want to get rid of Ubuntu and delete `ext4 #2` for Red Hat, for some reason I feel like `ext #2` is the second partition from the second time I installed it but I could be wrong.

Comment: There are two ext4s so be sure you know what I mean, only ext4 with the 112.75G is likely Ubuntu, but also, don't delete just yet, I have to ask, when you power on your computer , you are likely presented with a GRUB menu, and there is a list of OS to choose as well as a countdown and it will boot that OS unless you interfere with the countdown. So what OS does the countdown boot into, when you don't interfere with it?

Comment: it boots into Ubuntu do I have to go into bios and change the primary boot option?

Comment: @user454038 You are correct.  My bad. I got the dev name associations correct, but misread the question about which one is not wanted/not wanted.  Hopefully, OP caught this, based on your comment.